# MongoDB Java col.replaceOne stuck

Tags: java, mongodb

I am currently developing a backend with MongoDB in Java but got a very strange problem. If i call the replaceOne Method on a MongoCollection the command wont get executed and the execution stucks. The update is done asynchronous and in other cases the replace works.

There's no Exception or similar. I also checked the generated Document and tried to update it manually and it worked. The connection to the database works and the col.getCount() also returns the right number.

```
public void updateUserStats(DatabaseStats user_settings) {
    MongoCollection<Document> col = this.database.getCollection("user_stats");
    System.out.println("[DEBUG] GOT COLLECTION");
    col.replaceOne(Filters.eq("UUID", user_settings.getUuid()), user_settings.createSetDocument(), UPSERT);
    System.out.println("[DEBUG] DONE REPLACE");
}
```

This is how i am updating the database. The "GOT COLLECTION" gets called, but the "DONE REPLACEMENT" not. I am using the mongo-java-driver version 3.5.0 and Java 8.

Also if someone is interested in the Object DatabaseStats: https://hastebin.com/gogurimepe.js
And an example document.toJson(): https://hastebin.com/buhorajoyo.json
(Values are matching the expectations)

Any ideas?
(First post here, I hope i done it alright)